# Ceiling mounted punching bag without compromising structure or floor above

Tags: basement, foundation, mounting, joists, structural

This question is regarding the safest way of installing a heavy punching bag of 100 lbs from the basement ceiling. Above the basement ceiling is a wood floor. The goal is to sleep soundly at night knowing that we don't have to worry about damaging the ceiling/floor or wall structure.

**QUESTION 1:**

Is one of these methods, or another method, the best and safest for hanging and using a 100 lbs punching bag and not having to worry about it damaging the floor structure or the floor above over time?:

***(a)***

- Adding 3 or 4 beams parallel between the existing basement ceiling joists
- Adding a perpendicular beam that will screw into those parallel beams (so that the weight is distributed amongst those beams)
- Attaching the ceiling mount (Note 1) to that perpendicular beam

***(b)***

- Adding a beam parallel between the basement ceiling joists
- Attaching the ceiling mount (Note 1) to that one parallel beam

***(c)***

- Adding a steel beam resting on solid wall at each end, joined by a wood beam going across the ceiling.
- Ceiling mount/bag would hang on this beam.

*Note 1: The ceiling mount is designed to absorb the shock produced by hitting the bag. The bag hangs from the [ceiling mount](https://rivalboxing.us/products/copy-of-rival-ceilling-mount-system-150-lbs), which is screwed into the ceiling beam.*

**QUESTION 2**

What is the best way to secure/install the parallel beams or, if option (c) is recommended, the steel beams?

**QUESTION 3**

My assumption is that hanging anything from the existing joists, or even making holes in the existing joists, is best avoided so as not to weaken them or tamper with the existing floor structure. Is this a valid assumption?

Answer (score 4):

Hanging a 100lb weight from a joist should be no different (structurally) than putting a 100lb weight on top of the joist.  So since a 200lb person can easily stand on the floor above the joist, just hanging a 100lb bag from it shouldn't cause any issues.

The larger issue here is going to be what happens when you actually *use* the bag.  Speaking from experience, it's going to be similar to having a bunch of kids running around the house - things will shake and rattle a bit, and over time you might get some cracks in plaster/drywall, but it shouldn't cause any *structural* issues.

ETA: I missed the part where you mentioned using a mount that absorbs a lot of the shock from use.  If that's the case, then you can probably ignore my second paragraph.

Comment: True although I’ll note that the floorboards do spread the weight of the 200lb person onto several joists.